# Assets get converted into 'text/html' on nginx server after posting dist coming from ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx

After doing ng build--prod of our angular application and pushing the dist folder on nginx server, images or pdf inside assets folder are getting automatically converted into 'text/html' format.

Comment: You need to configure nginx to set correct mime types

Comment: @David Thanks for reply, I already have configured mime types in server.Likewise types{image/png png;} along with image other types and for pdf also but still it is not working...Please suggest